# How would I make something like jQuery plugins subsite?

Tags: web-hosting, php, hostgator

I'm currently creating a website. Part of the website I want people to be able to have their own sub site that they can add content (text files with descriptions) to (think jQuery plugins page). Is there any package that does this?

If not, what would be the process of learning how to do this?

I'm using HostGator so I can do it in PHP, Perl, ROR, and CGI (not sure what that is, I think it's Perly). I would rather PHP as I think it has the lowest learning curve, and I've dabbled in it already.

My goal is to have a site where I can post content on the main page and other people will have their own directories (example.com/user/johnDoe) where they can post file types of my choosing but I'm still the site master and they're just my minions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Plugins site is built with [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).
Beyond that, it's functionally a pretty standard community site, except that the content being submitted by users is a plugin rather than say, blog posts. Here's a [node](http://drupal.org/node/206724) listing a bunch of modules commonly used for building such things. It might serve as a bit of foundation for your research.